# Using WINDBG with Silverlight 4.0.60831.0

Tags: silverlight, windbg

I just upgraded my machine to Silverlight version 4.0.60831.0 to see if it would help with some Memory leaking issues that I'm seeing. 
Now when I try to use WinDbg and attempt to load the SOS.dll I realize that there is no SOS.dll for the .60831 version. I loaded the previous 4.0.60531.0 version, but when I attempt to dumpheap, I get the following error:

The version of SOS does not match the version of CLR you are debugging.  Please
load the matching version of SOS for the version of CLR you are debugging.

CLR Version: 4.0.60831.0

SOS Version: 4.0.60531.0

I tried the .loadby command and that was unsuccessful as well

0:028> .loadby sos coreclr

The call to LoadLibrary(c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60831.0\sos) failed, Win32 error 0n126
    "The specified module could not be found."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
This makes sense because there is no SOS.dll file in that directory.

Is there something I missed somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

sos.dll for Silverlight 4 comes with [Silverlight 4 Developer Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18149).

Comment: Right, and that version is 4.0.60531 and the latest version is .605831

Answer (score 0):

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=146060

It will download Silverlight_Developer.exe which will contain sos.dll 4.0.60831.0
which is the corresponding developer runtime for Silverlight.